# Is asking your potential rapist to use a condom considered giving consent in the US?

Tags: united-states, consent

Is asking somebody who is forcing themselves on you to use a condom enough to give him / her consent? If you consider yourself being the victim of rape, but you ask for the person to use a condom is that giving consent?

I have heard it said that consent cannot be implied or inferred; it is either given or it is not.  Also in some cases people can be unable to give consent out of a legal point of view even if expressed in an otherwise normal way. Like a 16 years being before the age of legal consent. So basically the logic is boolean.

This makes me think asking for a condom is not the same as consent.

Comment: Can you, please, clarify this a bit?  If you are capable of consent and you give consent, then it's not rape.  So you can't give consent to a rapist *as such*.  With the current phrasing, this is a loaded question.  Is there a form of duress that is present?

Comment: I doubt it would be any more consent than if a victim asked their rapist not to hurt them.